# Is there a VS Code extension to strip JS objects and arrays of whitespaces and carriage returns?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a VS Code extension that allows me to select with the mouse a block of JS code like this:

```
{
  qwe: 123,
  asd: 'qwe',
  dfg: true,
}
```

and format it like this:

```
{qwe:123,asd:'qwe',dfg:true}
```

Another example. Select this block with the mouse:

```
[
  'qwe',
  true,
  123,
]
```

right click on the selection, choose "format me" from the VS Code menu. The code becomes:

```
['qwe',true,123]
```

Is there an extension that does this?

Could I do it by configuring a linter?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a minifier?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say if you are formatting stuff by hand yourself you're doing it wrong. That's what prettier et al are for.

Comment: Some code formatters will allow this, although I wouldn't--harder to read. If you want a minifier use a minifier.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm going to go out on a limb and say if you are commenting stuff without any idea of the context where it comes from, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mocha's comment, I went looking for a minifier extension.

I tried several of them. [This one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qczhang.es6-css-minify-qczhang) seems the most versatile for my requirement.